# Can never get all dependencies for opencv on raspberry pi 3

Tags: dependencies, raspberry-pi3, opencv3.1

I've been trying everything to install dependencies for opencv. First I wen through the tutorial:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/18/install-guide-raspberry-pi-3-raspbian-jessie-opencv-3/

After doing this I was still left with over 100 unmet dependencies so I ran

```
sudo apt-get build-dep opencv --fix-missing
```

This returned:

```
Reading package lists... Done

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

The following NEW packages will be installed:

  texlive-base texlive-fonts-extra

0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

117 not fully installed or removed.

Need to get 0 B/272 MB of archives.

After this operation, 768 MB of additional disk space will be used.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y

Preconfiguring packages ...

(Reading database ... 139246 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to unpack .../texlive-base_2016.20170123-5_all.deb ...

Unpacking texlive-base (2016.20170123-5) ...

dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt

dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-base_2016.20170123-5_all.deb (--unpack):

 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/texlive/texlive-en/archive/live-2004.tex.gz' to '/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/texlive/texlive-en/archive/live-2004.tex.gz.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream

Preparing to unpack .../texlive-fonts-extra_2016.20170123-5_all.deb ...

Unpacking texlive-fonts-extra (2016.20170123-5) ...

dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt

dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-fonts-extra_2016.20170123-5_all.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/adobe/sourcesanspro/SourceSansPro-Semibold.pfb' to '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/adobe/sourcesanspro/SourceSansPro-Semibold.pfb.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream

Errors were encountered while processing:

 /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-base_2016.20170123-5_all.deb

 /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-fonts-extra_2016.20170123-5_all.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

E: Failed to process build dependencies
```

Then I ran

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing
```

And got:

```
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree     
Reading state information... Done    
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
texlive-fonts-recommended : 
Depends: texlive-base (>= 2016.20170123-2) but it is not installed
Recommends: tex-gyre but it is not installed
Recommends: texlive-fonts-recommended-doc but it is not installed
Recommends: tipa (>= 2:1.2-2.1) but it is not installed
texlive-latex-base : 
Depends: texlive-base (>= 2016.20170123-2) but it is not installed
Recommends: texlive-latex-base-doc but it is not installed
texlive-latex-extra : Depends: texlive-base (>= 2016.20170123-2) but it is not installed
Recommends: texlive-generic-extra but it is not installed
Recommends: texlive-latex-extra-doc but it is not installed
texlive-latex-recommended : Depends: texlive-base (>= 2016.20170123-2) but it is not installed
Recommends: prosper (>= 1.00.4+cvs.2006.10.22) but it is not installed
Recommends: texlive-latex-recommended-doc but it is not installed
texlive-pictures : Depends: texlive-base (>= 2016.20170123-2) but it is not installed
Recommends: texlive-pictures-doc but it is not installed
Recommends: tk but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I did that:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

And got:

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

Correcting dependencies... Done

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

fonts-cabin fonts-comfortaa fonts-croscore fonts-ebgaramond fonts ebgaramond-extra fonts-font-awesome fonts-freefont-otf fonts-gfs-artemisia fonts-gfs-complutum fonts-gfs-didot fonts-gfs-neohellenic fonts-gfs-olga fonts-gfs-solomos fonts-junicode fonts-lobster fonts-lobstertwo fonts-noto-hinted fonts-oflb-asana-math fonts-roboto-hinted fonts-sil-gentiumplus fonts-sil-gentiumplus-compact fonts-stix ttf-adf-accanthis ttf-adf-gillius ttf-adf-universalis


Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.

The following additional packages will be installed:

  lmodern texlive-base

Suggested packages:

  ghostscript gv | postscript-viewer perl-tk

The following NEW packages will be installed:

  lmodern texlive-base

0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

117 not fully installed or removed.

Need to get 9,461 kB/25.2 MB of archives.

After this operation, 80.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y

Get:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf lmodern all 2.004.5-3 [9,461 kB]

Fetched 9,461 kB in 9s (1,010 kB/s)

Preconfiguring packages ...

(Reading database ... 139246 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to unpack .../texlive-base_2016.20170123-5_all.deb ...

Unpacking texlive-base (2016.20170123-5) ...

dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: 

compressed data is corrupt

dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-base_2016.20170123-5_all.deb (--unpack):

 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/texlive/texlive-en/archive/live-2004.tex.gz' to '/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/texlive/texlive-en/archive/live-2004.tex.gz.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream

Selecting previously unselected package lmodern.

Preparing to unpack .../lmodern_2.004.5-3_all.deb ...

Unpacking lmodern (2.004.5-3) ...

Errors were encountered while processing:

/var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-base_2016.20170123-5_all.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I tried

sudo apt-get -f install

And pretty much got the same thing. Always a problem with this tex live-base! I have no idea what to do since I am not a command line expert and am certainly not used to downloading dependencies... It seems like something is corrupt or encountering an end-of-file right? What do I do?

I just really need openCV on my Raspberry 3! Does someone know if I can find an image of Raspbian WITH openCV pre-installed? NOT FOR 90$!!!! :)

Or just help me with doing it by myself?

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed IT!!!!!! Just sudo rm those 2 .deb files and redo apt-get build-dep opencv and it worked!!!!

Not sure if that's gonna fix everything but I'm one step closer :)